# detect scroll to bottom of a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

i want to detect that i reach the bottom of a div
my div is 400px height with overflow hidden
i don't know the normal height but more than 400px

i'm using this code but it doesn't work
any idea?

```
if($("#article-txt").scrollTop() + $("#article-txt").height() == $("#article-txt")[0].scrollHeight) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#parentdiv").scroll(function(){
    if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() === $(this).outerHeight()) {
        alert(1);
    };
});
```

Works. You need to add the parent div name, not the scrolling Div itself.