# How to detect scroll to bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll, detect

This is code that detect if user is scroll to bottom.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var distance = $(window).scrollTop() -$(document).height() + $(window).height();
  console.log(distance);
});
```

when I reload the web browser(chrome), and The window scroll is down to bottom,The "distance" value is 0 or -1 in the chrome.
I don't know why this occurs;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823645/detect-scroll-to-bottom-of-a-div?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Convert `$(document).height()` and `$(window).height()` value to the integer value as below,

```
parseInt($(document).height());
parseInt($(window).height());
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. but same result.

Comment: @OhJongAm your code is working for me in chrome...may be something wrong with jQuery version...i am using jQuery 1.9

Comment: I can't upgrade jQuery becasue of Other jquery plugins. Other plugins run at jquery version <= 1.8.3. So current my jquery version is 1.8.3...